# Select de periodo entre horários

Tags: mysql, sql, algoritmo, lógica

Estou tentando montar um `sql` para verificar se há algum registro entre horários informados, mas não está saindo, fiz alguns testes mas sem sucesso.

Por exemplo, um registro do banco que contenha esses dois horários, como inicial e final respectivamente:

> HoraIni: 8:00 e HoraFim: 8:30

Qualquer período que comece ou termine durante esse período informador a cima deve ser selecionado/retornado no sql

```
Periodos que devem retornar o registro citado a cima
7:45 até 8:15
8:00 até 8:15
```

Porém períodos como estes devem retornar nada:

```
Periodos sem retorno
7:45 até 8:00
8:30 até 8:45
```

É um problema de lógica, onde não consigo acertar os `maior, menor e igual` para retornar o que preciso.

O banco é um `MYSQL` os campos são `TIME` e esse select rodará em uma função `Java`, essa parte não é o problema, mas fica aqui para sanar as possíveis dúvidas.

Espero que tenha ficado claro, já olhei vários exemplos e não achei nada, se atenta ao detalhe que os horários são iguais de inicio e fim, onde o mesmo horário que termina um registro começa outro.

Comment: O tipo das colunas HoraIni e HoraFim é timestamp?

Comment: Não ficou claro não.

Comment: As colunas são do tipo Time apenas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa dos registros onde Hora inicial estiver entre 8 e 8:30, OU, hora final estiver entre 8 e 8:30

Sendo assim, podemos ter a seguinte query:

```
Select * from tabela 
where 
(horaini >= '8:00' and horaini <= '8:30')
 OR
(horafim >= '8:00' and horafim <= '8:30')
```

> ps. Você não colocou estrutura das tabelas, nem mesmo a query que está tentando, logo, fiz apenas um exemplo com os dados que foram passados.  Se precisar de mais detalhes, edite a pergunta acrescentando o que falta.

Edit:

```
Select * from tabela 
where 
(horaini >= '8:00' and horaini < '8:30')
 OR
(horafim > '8:00' and horafim <= '8:30')
```

Comment: A ideia achei válida, mas temo que dependendo do motor de sql ele interprete o comparador como ordem lexicográfica. Isso só iria afetar nos casos de horários inválidos, mas mesmo assim achei válido levantar essa observação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, pois é, dei como exemplo tendo base no que ele postou, como se a coluna fosse do tipo `TIME`. Acho que a dificuldade estava sendo na lógica, por isso não me importei em confirmar isso antes. Caso ele não resolva, terá que explicar melhor seu problema =]

Comment: Obrigado Rovann, é um problema de lógica mesmo, porém o problema continua. Se eu adicionar um registro que `termina as 8:00` e adicionar outro que `começa as 8:00`, ele não deveria retornar pois são dois horários distintos um terminou e outro esta começando, mas com seu select acima, ele está retornando o registro que terminou :/

Comment: @P.Dominges basta mudar a condição de `>=` para `>` e então não será retornardo tal registro.

Comment: @P.Dominges coloque alguns dados que estão no seu banco para termos de exemplo, e qual é a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Rovann, obrigado! Deu certo, como você disse, retirei a condição `=` onde a comparação é feita entre a hora inicial e final e deixei onde a comparação é entre dois campos iniciais ou finais. Na sua resposta ficaria `horaini < 8:30` e `horafim > 8:00` mantendo igual as outras duas comparações. Obrigado!